# Creating virtual layer or view table from original table using pivot table on QGIS?

Tags: qgis-3, sql, virtual-layer, pivot-table

I have a table and I need to produce a virtual layer with pivot or crosstable command.

Is it possible on QGIS 3.6 or 3.8?

My original sql is:

```
select cd_setor, Name, Path_relativo 
from Fotos
order by cd_setor, Name, Path_relativo
```

[image]

The result that I intend is like as I show below.

[image]

Comment: Is impossible to do this?